# Update text in the pycharm console

Tags: python, printing, pycharm

I'm trying to make a script to calculate pi, but by increasing the steps in the main for loop, it drastically increases in the time it takes to calculate. Sometimes its hard to tell if its doing anything at all. So to fix this I put the following in the main for loop:

```
# prints the progress percentage (or pp)
pp = (i/rolls)*100
print(pp.__round__(pp_decimals))
```

rolls in the total number of times the loop will execute.

But this presents a new problem, this ends up printing ALOT of text, and all the print calls end up lagging my pc as well as clogging up the terminal. So my question is, how can I edit the text or delete previous text in order to clear up the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best to approach your problem in a different way. I assume that `i` is loop counter so you can print progress percentage in every `t` times instead clearing the output:

```
# prints the progress percentage (or pp)
if i % 10 == 0: # t is 10 in this example
   pp = (i/rolls)*100
   print(pp.__round__(pp_decimals))
```